# Flutter how to open pdf using web browser

Tags: flutter

How to open pdf from url address in flutter?
I try call window like this:
[image]

And select there application for open pdf file.
I try do it using libraries:

- https://pub.dev/packages/pdfx
- https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

But none of them cannot do it. Any ideas or samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force webview using

```dart
Future<void> _launchInBrowser(Uri url) async {
    if (!await launchUrl(
      url,
      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
    )) {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

or to load it in an inapp web view

```
Future<void> _launchInWebViewOrVC(Uri url) async {
    if (!await launchUrl(
      url,
      mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView,
      webViewConfiguration: const WebViewConfiguration(
          headers: <String, String>{'my_header_key': 'my_header_value'}),
    )) {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Comment: My solution was similar to Your, but I do not have ` mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication` after add this, it works! Thank You one more time ;)